# Why Spring related dependencies are forbidden on http://repository.jboss.org

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss

I am getting forbidden error on all the maven dependencies on http://repository.jboss.org.
Does anyone knows, whats the reason and how can I fix these warnings.

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to jboss-public-repo (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/): Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

Repository Section :

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repo</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
            <name>JBoss public available repo</name>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: It would help to show the `repositories` section of your POM